# Sort items based on results that may or may not be in join table in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

```
items(id)
user_items(id, user_id, item_id, status)
```

I have a table `items` with a `has_many` relationship with `user_items`. I would like to sort by "top items" where the items at the top of the list have the most `user_items` with a `status` of 1(approved).

The sql query that I came up with seems a little ugly but seems to mostly do the job:

```
SELECT items.* FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN user_items ON user_items.item_id = items.id 
        GROUP BY items.id, user_items.status 
        ORDER BY (user_items.status = #{UserItem.statuses[:approved]}) DESC NULLS LAST, 
            COUNT(items.id) DESC
```

The problem with this is that I am getting duplicate items in the results so I have to post process with something like this: `Item.find_by_sql(sql).uniq{|item| item.id}`

How can I avoid having to call `uniq` here? Is there a more efficient query that I could write to accomplish the same thing? And is there a cleaner way to write this in Rails where I don't have to use `find_by_sql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want items with the most `user_items`, then I would recommend a query like this:

```
select i.*,
       (select count(*)
        from user_items ui
        where ui.item_id = i.it and ui.status = 1
       ) as numusers
from items i
order by numusers desc;
```

You *can* do this with the `left join` and `group by` as well:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i LEFT OUTER JOIN
     user_items ui
     ON ui.item_id = i.id AND ui.status = 1
GROUP BY i.id
ORDER BY COUNT(u.user_id) DESC;
```

Comment: This works well but what if I wanted to sort ties by `user_items.updated_at`?

Comment: @bos37 . . . That doesn't make sense.  There could be more than one match.  You can add something like `order by min(ui.updated_at)` to the `order by` clause.